# How Do I Install Core Plot

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-plot

I need to use core plot in my iphone app. Where do I get it and can someone tell me in plain English in detail how to get it up and running onmy machine?

Here is a copy of the ReadMe file sent with the SDK:

```
1. Copy the CorePlotSDK directory to ~/Library/SDKs/  (WHERE IS THIS FOLDER LOCATED??)

2. Add to your project's .PCH file:

#import <CorePlot/CorePlot.h>

3. Open Project -> Edit Project Settings and for All Configurations:

    3a. Add to Additional SDKS: 

$HOME/Library/SDKs/CorePlotSDK/${PLATFORM_NAME}.sdk     (WHERE IS THIS FILE LOCATED???)

    3b. Add to Other Linker Flags:

-ObjC -all_load -lCorePlot                              (WHAT DOES THIS MEAN??)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to put this delicately but before you learn to use Core Plot you might learn to use Google, Bing or some other search engine.

[Core Plot Home Page](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/)

I got that by typing in "Core Plot".

### Edit

(Based on new info)

(1) The tilde indicates the path to the home folder of the current user although in the case of the Library folder you can also use the Library at the root level of the system volume. Putting in the latter location makes it available to all user accounts on the system.

(2) The .pch file is in the "other sources" group of the template projects.

(3a) $HOME means the path to the users home folder. So it would be: "/Users/User-Name/...". the Platform name is the version of the iOS you are building for. If the path doesn't exist, you have to create the directories manually.

(3b) Get info on the projects target. Under the build tab, scroll down to the "Linking" heading. There is a field for "Other Linker Flags". copy and past the line into that field.

Comment: Got it running finally Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the snark. I was in a mood yesterday.

Comment: TechZen, I'm doing all the steps but I'm getting a bunch of linker errors. How did you managed to make it work?

Comment: @tuler -- You might want to post your own question with the linker errors you are getting. There's to many possible errors.

Answer (score 1):

I am confused, are you having problems because you can't find the files or because you can't parse the pathnames they gave you.  `~/Library/SDKs/` starts in your home directory and then is the `SDKs` folder in your `Library` folder.  They `SDKs` folder may not exists but you can create it.

The second file you could not find would also be under the same set of directories, once you install it, it should be easy to find.

As far as the linker flags go, the important thing they do is tell the linker to load the CorePlot Framework.  Do you need help understanding them or how to use them?