# Can anyone tell me the steps to install the CorePlot framework for iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-plot

I am getting confused on setting header path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install CorePlot for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919103/install-coreplot-for-iphone)

Comment: Please don't post duplicates of your unanswered question. Instead, edit the original to make it more clear or add requested detail. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Do I Install Core Plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009140/how-do-i-install-core-plot)

Answer (score 0):

Set the header path to the *framework* folder within the folder where you've installed the core-plot source. And (this is the important part) check the *Recursive* checkbox. Also, make sure you are setting the Build options for the project, not the target. You can ensure you're doing this by going to Project -> Edit Project Settings (at least in Xcode 3.2).